# DynamoDB Scan with filter, matching 'is-in-set' conditions

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-scan

I'm trying to use a Scan operation on a DynamoDB table to match items with given 'tags'.  The tags for an item are stored in a single set attribute.  E.g.:

```
machine-1: tags = "windows", "iis", "64bit"
machine-2: tags = "windows", "fs"
```

Now, I have a support case open with Premium Support, but it's taking some amount of time.  What I want to do is match machines where 'tags' contains the entry "windows" *and* "iis".

I can match a single one by using the `CONTAINS` mode, and specifying a single AttributeValue with a string value of "windows", for example.

However, `CONTAINS` does not support sets in a single AttributeValue, or multiple AttributeValues.  It gives an error.

So I tried `IN` (something AWS premium support also suggested): however, whether I use a single AttributeValue (even just looking for "windows" again or multiple ones), I get zero results.

The documentation for `IN` is pretty poor.  The operation is described in 4 uninformative words, in fact: "*checks for exact matches*".

While I wait for support possibly going on with a few more rounds of Q&A, is anyone reading this familiar with this kind of query with Scan?  (If you could, please test what you're saying in your answer first: I think I have tried the obvious ones!)

For ref, Scan documentation: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html

Comment: When I get a response (well, a good one: no good so far) from premium support I will post it here.  Taking a long time, but they're contacting the developers directly now..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This from AWS premium support:

*"Hello.*

*I got confirmation from Dynamo DB this is currently not supported. CONTAINS against a set can only be performed with a single value. "*

Urgh.  So now I will create a new attribute for each possible tag, with a 'True' or 'False' in each column, and filter my Scan on that.

Comment: you could have done "tags contains windows or tags contains iis"